# Python how to use a string to fill a dictionary in one go?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, printing

I have this for example

```
Dict = {'Hello':'World', 'Hi':'Again'}
x = (str(Dict))
Dict2 = {x}
print (Dict2)
```

I understand why it doesn't work that way but i'm new to python and have no idea what i'm doing.
I'd like to be able to export my dictionary to a variable (here x) and then able to fill another dictionary with it. I don't want to use the dict.copy() command, beacause the variable x will be stored on a txt file.
Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it beats the purpose"?  It sounds like all you are doing is copying it, so why don't you want to use `copy`?

Comment: You can't do `{x}` because you need a key-val assignment in dictionaries no matter what. So try `{'Dict' : x}` or something?

Comment: I'm trying to put the dictionary on a text file with file.write() and reading the string with file.read(). i'm doing this to save variables between progam uses.

Comment: Looks like you want to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for your data.

Comment: @TheD0ubleT: You should mention that in your question, then.  For that purpose, what you want is [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually want to use a string to do the copying, you can say:

```
Dict2 = eval(repr(Dict))
```

but there's no reason you would ever need to do that. Use `dict.copy()` instead.

EDIT: Based on what you said in the comments, `json`, as another user has already pointed out, is the best way to go. That would look like this:

```
import json 

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    json.dump(Dict, f)

with open("file.txt") as f:
    Dict2 = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Thanks, works great, better and simpler as expected.

Comment: You should be aware that this is much less efficient than `dict.copy()`. There is **no reason this is ever a good idea**. Additionally, if you found my answer helpful, please upvote and accept it.

Comment: `eval` is never good idea. Better to use `ast.literal_eval`. And in this case `json` or `pickle` are the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're looking for is to save a dict-like string representation to a file so you can load it later, use [the `json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).  (This is not at all the same as "exporting a dictionary to a variable", but your comment indicates that what you're really trying to do is save a dictionary to a file.)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to specifically address what you asked is:

```
Dict = {'Hello':'World', 'Hi':'Again'}
x = str(Dict)
Dict2 = dict((y.split(':') for y in x[1:-1].strip().replace(" ","").replace("'","").split(',')))
```

or if you want to use dictionary comprehension

```
Dict2 = {y.split(':')[0]:y.split(':')[1] for y in x[1:-1].strip().replace(" ","").replace("'","").split(',')}
```

But I really **would not suggest doing it this way**. Instead I was suggest looking at either [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to save the dictionary to file.